# Why does this abort right on the UIlabel?

Tags: swift, xcode

I connected the `UILabel` and `UIButton` but is still aborts. Please help me fix this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        counterLabel.text = "0"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    var counterNum: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.counterNum += 1
        self.counterLabel.text = String(self.counterNum)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your issue exactly ? Do you have an crash log?

Comment: Why did you include `func didReceiveMemoryWarning`? Please only add _relevant_ code to your question.

Comment: When it aborts, what does Xcode show?

Comment: 2017-03-03 18:43:48.521 #57[30240:689945] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_57.ViewController 0x7fd2cef029c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Tap.'     This is what it says

Comment: Please edit your question, remove unnecessary code and add this information. If you improve your question, you have a better chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: We need more info. What "abort" means? Which is the error message displayed? Thank you.

Comment: Ashley Mills,  Got it thanks for the advice. I'm a noob.

Comment: Do a search on "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key". This has been asked and answered a million times before.

Comment: it says Tread1:signal SIGABRT

Comment: It looks like in this case you made an _outlet_ to Tap whereas what you actually want is an _action_ from the button. Or maybe you made the outlet to Tap when you intended an outlet to counterLabel.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your outlet connect in your storyboard for counterLabel. It seems you forget to do the outlet connection.

Comment: it says Tread1:signal  SIGABRT